# Why won't Ubuntu boot?

Tags: system-installation

i got a pretty bad laptop (a Dell Latitude d800), and I'm not able to install Ubuntu 12.10.  When I tried to boot, the installer told me there was a problem with my CPU.  I really want to run Ubuntu; is this a problem with my Ubuntu disc or with my laptop? Win7 currently runs fine, so I suspect that it is a hardware problem.

Comment: What is the exact error message that you got when booting Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

The minimum requirements are:

```
700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
512 MiB RAM (system memory)
5 GB of hard-drive space
VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
```

It should run on older computers.  More likely, the problem is that you burned a 64-bit disc and stuck it into a computer that does not have a 64-bit processor.  Try burning a 32-bit disc or USB drive and trying again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [QuantalQuetzal/ReleaseNotes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop)

**System Requirements**

The minimum memory requirement for Ubuntu 12.10 is 768 MB of memory and 5 GB of disk space for Ubuntu Desktop. Note that some of your system's memory may be unavailable due to being used by the graphics card. If your computer has only the minimum amount of memory, the installation process will take longer than normal; however, it will complete successfully, and the system will perform adequately once installed.

Your system has only 512MB of RAM so it wont work.  However you should be able to use either [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) without any problems.

[**Xubuntu System Requirements**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/ReleaseNotes/Xubuntu)

Minimum system requirements for Xubuntu fall roughly between Ubuntu Server and Desktop:

```
512 MB of system memory (RAM)
5 GB of disk space
Graphics card and monitor capable of 800*600 resolution
```

[**Lubuntu System Requirements**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/ReleaseNotes/Lubuntu)

A Pentium II or Celeron system with 128 MB of RAM is probably a bottom-line configuration that may yield slow yet usable system with a standard lubuntu desktop.

Make sure you get the 32-bit download.

I would try them both without installing from a Live USB or CD/DVD, check everything works OK then install the one you prefer.  These are official variants of Ubuntu and as such supported here.

Answer (score 0):

A test is done, you can find it here :

[Dell Latitude D800](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LaptopTestingTeam/Old/DellLatitudeD800)

maybe you can not install 12.10 on this machine..

Answer (score -1):

Check your installation media and check about 32/64 bit choose the suitable media for installa